# How to improve OCR results of tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm having problems with tesseract conducting OCR of numbers. This picture

[image]

is recognised as

‘I .38)

I'm using -psm 6 as parameter. Are there any better ways to recognise numbers? Do I need to configure tesseract or is there any additional pre processing needed of the image?

Answer (score 3):

I rescaled to 300DPI and got the correct result.

Comment: Is rescaling generally something that is recommended?

Comment: It's normally required for screenshots for their low resolutions. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#is-there-a-minimum-text-size-it-wont-read-screen-text